# C# Dictionary<T,K> thread-safety with single writer multiple reader

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, base-class-library

> A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently,
>   as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating
>   through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In
>   the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the
>   collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. To allow the
>   collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing,
>   you must implement your own synchronization.

This is what MSDN says.

I don't want to use ConcurrentDictionary if it is not necessary

I assume, if there is only one thread performing writer operations on `Dictionary<T,K>`, it is safe for other threads to perform simple reading operations(like `TryGetValue` not enumeration) at the same time without acquiring a lock, am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old [`System.Collections.Hashtable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is safe for multiple-readers-single-writer scenarios, that is, any number of threads can read from the Hashtable, but at most one thread can modify it at the same time. (The writer thread can safely modify the Hashtable while the readers are reading from it).

The generic `Dictionary<T,K>` is not safe for such scenarios - use [`ConcurrentDictionary<T,K>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Note that `System.Collections.Hashtable` and `ConcurrentDictionary<T,K>` use completely different implementation and provide different API. `ConcurrentDictionary<T,K>` fits well for such scenarios as lazy initialization and read-through cache. `System.Collections.Hashtable` is more performant as it is a kind of lock-free data structure, while `ConcurrentDictionary<T,K>` uses thread synchronization marshaled to Windows API.

Answer (score 6):

> I assume, if there is only one thread performing writer operations on
>   Dictionary, it is safe for other threads to perform simple
>   reading operations(like TryGetValue not enumeration) at the same time
>   without acquiring a lock

No. Your assumption is wrong. It is safe only when no writers are modifying the dictionary not when you have a single writer.

[ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is exactly designed to be used in this scenario. That said I'd just use [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of *Re-inventing the wheel*.